# Сортировка уровня фактора

Tags: r

Задание:

> Создайте из вектора **cols** неупорядоченный фактор **cols_f** так, чтобы его уровни следовали в порядке, обратном алфавитному.

Дано:

> cols <- c('red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow')

Решение:

> cols_f<-rev(sort(as.factor(cols)))
>
> Error: Неверно закодированы уровни

Почему неверно ?

Comment: `factor(..., levels=...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно выбрать уникальные значения и отсортировать, а потом их передать как аргумент levels

```
cols_f<-factor(cols, levels=rev(sort(unique(cols))))
```